# load more than 50 images on a single page loaded in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, performance, iframe

We have multiple books on a server which are loading only via javascript, css and html. Nothing is coming from database, all the content are coming from their corresponding directories. Single book is loading in iframe on same domain and all have more than 30 pages and each page could have multiple images. The size of single book is around 30 MB. Directory structure of all books are similar except their base directory name and the image names for all pages of books are same. So only difference there is unique Book directory name. Could somebody help me how can i increase page load time and overall performance? I have already compress the images and minified css and javascript files.

Comment: Where is the 'book' stored and how? if it's basically embedded into your HTML/JS then not much we can do. You should seek size reduction if you're loading 30mb web page (That's a lot..), perhaps AJAX calls requesting individual pages from the book is something you should look into for a start.

Comment: I agree, the only real solution for this is to load all your content "lazily" through ajax calls or something similar. Look up "Lazy Loading"

Comment: @Adriani6 thanks for reply. I can't use AJAX there, i need only solution in javascript without using server side language.

Comment: @Dale thanks, i will look into lazy load via javascript if this can do the trick.

Comment: @MandeepSingh But I haven't said anything about a backend server. You can split the book into separate text files or html sub pages on your server (the one you host this book) and load those files using Ajax when needed.

Comment: @Adriani6 thanks i will try to use this method